# How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, unix, selenium

I'm on EC2 instance. So there is no GUI.

```
$pip install selenium
$sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
```

Then I do this:

```
$Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &

$DISPLAY=:1 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar
05:08:31.227 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 19.0-b09
05:08:31.229 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.32-305-ec2 i386
05:08:31.233 INFO - v2.0 [b3], with Core v2.0 [b3]
05:08:32.121 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
05:08:32.122 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
05:08:32.123 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
05:08:32.124 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
05:08:32.124 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
05:08:32.291 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1186fab
05:08:32.292 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
05:08:32.295 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
05:08:32.295 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1ffb8dc
```

Great, everything should work now, right?

When I run my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

I get this:

```
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: If you're on a system without X running, display :0 should be available. Try running Xvfb :0 -- also see xvfb-run as mentioned by @ema

Comment: For future followers, I described my solution for Ubuntu Server: https://www.namekdev.net/2016/08/selenium-server-without-x-window-system-xvfb/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

open a terminal and run this command  `xhost +`. This commands needs to be run every time you restart your machine. If everything works fine may be you can add this to startup commands

Also make sure in your /etc/environment file there is a line

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

And then, run your tests to see if your issue is resolved.

All please note the comment from sardathrion below before using this.

Comment: You just need to execute java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar from command line and then run your tests

Comment: I'm on an EC2 instance, so there is no GUI.  xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"

Comment: @owa You also need the DISPLAY environment variable in the client environment.

Comment: `xhost +` is insecure.  Please do not use it.  If you have to use xhost, add the specific machine you want and not + (aka everything whatsoever).

Answer (score 183):

You can use [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) (a Python wrapper for Xvfb) to run headless WebDriver tests.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

[more info](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html)

---

You can also use [xvfbwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xvfbwrapper), which is a similar module (but has no external dependencies):

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()

# launch stuff inside virtual display here

vdisplay.stop()
```

or better yet, use it as a context manager:

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

with Xvfb() as xvfb:
    # launch stuff inside virtual display here.
    # It starts/stops in this code block.
```

Comment: @Andrei OSX doesn't use X11 by default

Comment: Used this answer to make it work with vagrant + PyCharm + Django on OS X: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29343109

Comment: I get a "browser appears to have exited" when I implement the pyvirtualdisplay code above

Comment: Message: Service /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Answer (score 46):

The easiest way is probably to use xvfb-run:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar
```

xvfb-run does the whole X authority dance for you, give it a try!

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Starting Xvfb on its own didn't seem to work for me, but using xvfb-run did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: The ``DISPLAY=:1`` is unnecessary; xvfb-run sets the DISPLAY environment variable to something else (usually ``:99``) before starting the specified command (in your case, ``java -jar selenium-server...``)

Answer (score 22):

This is the setup I use:

Before running the tests, execute:

```
export DISPLAY=:99
/etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

And after the tests:

```
/etc/init.d/xvfb stop
```

The `init.d` file I use looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

XVFB=/usr/bin/Xvfb
XVFBARGS="$DISPLAY -ac -screen 0 1024x768x16"
PIDFILE=${HOME}/xvfb_${DISPLAY:1}.pid
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb"
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --background --exec $XVFB -- $XVFBARGS
    echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb"
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
    echo "."
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/xvfb {start|stop|restart}"
  exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: I did exactly this and then ran my script. However, I still get this: Error: cannot open display: :0.   Also, do I need to run the selenium java server? It seems like it doesn't matter if I run it or not...

Comment: owalla, if you use WebDriver, then you don't need the Selenium Java Server.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Maven, you can use [xvfb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Zetten/xvfb-maven-plugin) to start xvfb before tests, run them using related `DISPLAY` environment variable, and stop xvfb after all.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is:

```
xvfb-run python ./selenium-script.py
```

No need to add:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
display.stop()
```

But now, with Selenium WebDriver, there's no need to run also `xvfb` anymore (see the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42572187/9962007) why).