# Is it possible to run Selenium scripts without having an X server running, too?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, headless

I have a python script that uses selenium RC; specifically webdriver.

I would love to have the script run as a post-commit hook, ideally through IE, Safari (if possible), Chrome & Firefox.

But I'm not sure what I'd need to do, since every time I run it on my local machine, a browser pops up.

I've heard of "saucelabs".  Is it the best solution?

Comment: I was struggling with this some time ago, so I'll share my solution - installation of Selenium and xvfb on Ubuntu Server:  https://www.namekdev.net/2016/08/selenium-server-without-x-window-system-xvfb/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you need to have X server running because Selenium requires a running browser and browsers need some kind of X server in order to run.

Fortunately there are many types of X servers and one of them is [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) aka X virtual framebuffer that does all the operations in memory and thus requires no screen.

Wikipedia has also some [nice examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

Also there are lots of questions here on SO for keywords `headless`, `xvfb` and `selenium`. Choose wisely ;)

**[Edit]**: [Here's a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/157176).