# I can't import urllib2

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://localhost/ehaat/index.php/log-in'
form_data = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
```

I am new to this urllib. So what is that I am doing wrong here? And also, can I use this to post data into a form (automating task of filling a form and click on submit) by taking random data's from files. I want to use this to test my website.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Users\iamhssingh\Documents\Python\url.py", line 2, in 
>       import urllib2 ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Comment: What is the error/non required behavior you are getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File "D:\Users\iamhssingh\Documents\Python\url.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Do I need to install something? I installed mechanize library a few minutes ago btw!

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that. Python 3.4

Comment: @HimanshuShankar See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#examples) for an example using `post`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

urllib2 was merged with urllib in python 3. Is a standard library in python 2 but not in 3.

Try this if you want to use the urlopen method

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
print(html)
```

Also:

> The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3.0
>   named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3

Comment: It does gives a response!
Can you give me a code that how do I post data in a form using this?  Or the thing that I am trying to do above?

Comment: Okay I will post another question!

Comment: @HimanshuShankar: And please don't ask **Provide me the code** question. First try it on your own and if you get any errors, come back here. We are here to help you out.

Comment: I have already searched a lot. And I had this answer too somewhere. But still I don't get it. How do I do what I am trying to do above using this? Now I get a error that urllib not present!

Comment: Here you have a similar question related to a POST with urllib in python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288930/how-to-pass-parameter-to-url-with-python-urlopen