# selenium driver getting not managing to load SOME pages

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

Using [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) through python on AWS ubuntu server to scrape dynamic pages with javascript (need to render full html). Finally got it working (thanks to [unable to call firefox from selenium in python on AWS machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039530/unable-to-call-firefox-from-selenium-in-python-on-aws-machine)) for most websites, except some that will consistently give me a "Problem loading page".

In iPython:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
```

The following work fine (and respond quickly):

```
driver.get('http://www.apple.com/')
print driver.title
>> Apple

driver.get('http://www.orange.com/')
print driver.title
>> Orange.com: Corporate Website of Orange
```

But the following lags for 2-3 minutes and then finally returns with a problem loading page:

```
driver.get('http://www.trivago.com/')
print driver.title
>> Problem loading page
```

Here's some more info on the attributes of the driver at that point, in case it helps:

```
{'_is_remote': False,
 'binary': <selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary at 0x296d590>,
 'capabilities': {u'acceptSslCerts': True,
  u'applicationCacheEnabled': True,
  u'browserConnectionEnabled': True,
  u'browserName': u'firefox',
  u'cssSelectorsEnabled': True,
  u'databaseEnabled': True,
  u'handlesAlerts': True,
  u'javascriptEnabled': True,
  u'locationContextEnabled': True,
  u'nativeEvents': True,
  u'platform': u'Linux',
  u'rotatable': False,
  u'takesScreenshot': True,
  u'version': u'26.0',
  u'webStorageEnabled': True},
 'command_executor':     <selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection.ExtensionConnection at 0x296d6d0>,
 'error_handler': <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler at 0x7f14f4d4bf50>,
 'profile': <selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile at 0x2418cd0>,
 'session_id': u'ece53830-2b9d-4a32-b692-777602190d0c'}
```

The same urls  *all*  work well when I do the same code locally (through the terminal on my Mac).

Comment: May be http://www.trivago.com/ inaccessible from your server? Try to get it using curl from server shell.

Comment: I think you need to add the following property in your Display settings: `lmportal.xvfb.id=":99"` or `lmportal.xvfb.id=99` (though, it would not explain why you've managed to open one URL and failed to open another).

Comment: @DmitryVakhrushev: Quick, short, and... spot on! Thanks a bunch.
Curl failed indeed:
  ~$ curl www.trivago.com
  curl: (7) Failed connect to www.trivago.com:80; Connection timed out

--> But now the question is: Why, and what to do about it?

Comment: @DmitryVakhrushev: Sorry dimitry: trying to vote you up, but I'm too new to stackoverflow to do so it seems.

barakmanos: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind if I have display problems.

Comment: Solved: I managed to access the problematic urls using a different proxy, using `curl URL --proxy IP:PORT`. Thanks again @DmitryVakhrushev for the initial tip.