# phanthomjs not loading few websites -selenium[python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using `phanthomjs selenium driver`.It is properly loading the contents for some sites.For some other sites it is not giving any contents and gives blank/empty screen shot.Please guide me to fix this issue.

```
OS- Redhat Linux,Selenium- 2.46,Phanthomjs version-1.9.1
```

Below sample site **stackoverflow** is working fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221027/selenium-driver-getting-not-managing-to-load-some-pages')
time.sleep(6)
print driver.page_source
driver.save_screenshot("/home/user/Desktop/file.png")
driver.quit()
```

If I try to access below sites it is not working:

```
https://ipleak.net/
https://www.whatismyip.com/
```

Comment: on phantomjs 2.0.0 it works fine. You may need to update it.

Comment: Hi,I found the issue I added this line `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` in service_args and now it is accessing https sites