# How to fix Selenium WebDriverException: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have installed firefox and Xvfb on my centos6.4 server to use selenium webdriver.

But, when I run the code, I got an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

**Error**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 
'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: None'
```

I read some related pages on stackoverflow and someone suggested to remove all files in tmp folder, so I did it. But, it still doesn't work.

Could anyone please give me a help?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 64, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 103, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited     before we could connect. The output was: None'
```

Comment: Which selenium and firefox versions do you use? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Mozilla Firefox 31.1.0.

Comment: I have installed selenium via pip command. It is "Version: 2.43.0"

Comment: One option: you can output `pip freeze` and see what is there for `selenium`.

Comment: Also, what if you try chrome? `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that selenium's version is 2.43.0.

Comment: When I run "webdriver.Chrome()", I got this error. "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path." I haven't installed "chrome" onto my server.

Comment: Hey, any progress with the issue? Did you have any success with chrome?

Comment: I have installed Google Chrome, but it's not working.When I run "webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/google-chrome")", I get this error."selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the ChromeDriver' "

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing this error. when I run $ google-chrome
, I get this error "google-chrome: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by google-chrome)"

Comment: I've tried updating gcc but I got errors while compiling it. This is beyond my capacity, I guess... I've spent more than at least 10 hours for selenium webdriver but no outcome at all. I feel kinda depressed now :(

Comment: There was a known bug which supposedly was fixed:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7823

However, I have the latest version of selenium and firefox but I also get the error you have here. I've double checked permissions on the python file as well as the /tmp directory which it writes logs too. Everything seems fine. I have no idea why it won't work.

Answer (score 76):

for Googlers, this answer didn't work for me, and I had to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039530/unable-to-call-firefox-from-selenium-in-python-on-aws-machine) instead. I am using AWS Ubuntu.

Basically, I needed to install Xvfb and then pyvirtualdisplay:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Once I had done that, this python code worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
print browser.page_source

browser.close()
display.stop()
```

Thanks to @That1Guy for the first answer

Answer (score 27):

I was running into this on an (headless) Ubuntu 14.04 server with Jenkins and xvfb installed. I had installed the latest stable Firefox (47) which started a build failing that ran a python script which used the Firefox driver for selenium (version 2.53).

Apparently Firefox 47+ is not compatible with the driver used in Selenium 2.53, and Selenium 3+ will be using a new driver called "Marionette" or "Gecko Driver" (which isn't officially released yet).

This page explains how to use the new driver pretty well, in several languages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Basically:

1. get/build the executable from the project on github: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases (and make sure it's perms are set to be executable, IE `chmod a+x /path/to/geckdriver-executable`)
2. rename/copy binary to "wires"
3. make sure the binary's location is added to the PATH that the build uses when executing the selenium test
4. update the selenium test to use the new driver

For Python, step 4 looked something like the following for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

Comment: If it was working for you in the past, and after a Firefox update you're now getting "WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.", this is probably the explanation.

Comment: Here's more info: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110#issuecomment-224413609. Alternatives to switching to Marionette right now are reverting to FF 46, or waiting for Mozilla to release a FF 47 patch that fixes this.

Comment: At step 3 I put the file at: `/usr/local/bin/wires`. Thanks!

Comment: The bug is now fixed in FF 47.0.1

Comment: Update: It appears that FF48 again create problems; neither the original webdriver.Firefox version or the version including marionette work (the second giving back "WebDriverException: Service wires unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1")

Answer (score 22):

I too had faced same problem.  I was on Firefox 47 and Selenium 2.53; I downgraded Firefox to 45. This worked.

1. Remove Firefox 47 first :

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge firefox
   ```
2. Check for available versions:

   ```
   apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
   ```

   It will show available firefox versions like:

   > Version: 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
   >   Version: 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
3. Install a specific version

   ```
   sudo apt-get install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
   ```
4. Next you have to not upgrade to the newer version again.

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold firefox
   ```
5. If you want to upgrade later

   ```
   sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: Thanks a million for this workaround. I was stuck with this problem for a while.

Comment: @sudhishkr I know the frustration... Glad the solution helped.

Comment: @AmoghJoshi is this a problem with selenium or Firefox? Has this been logged as bug with them?

Comment: @Shafaq  That's right its a problem with Selenium.It has been logged as a bug. Here's the link to change log : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/py/CHANGES. You can see they have tried to solve compatibility issues with firefox web driver.

Comment: Thanks bro, it's really useful with me

Answer (score 11):

Check your `DISPLAY` environment variable. Run `echo $DISPLAY` in the command line.

If nothing is printed, then you are running FireFox without any DISPLAY assigned. You should assign one! Run `export DISPLAY=:1` in the command line before running your python script.

Check this thread for more information: http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-1973.html

Comment: Helpful tip: If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 in Headless mode, you likely want `export DISPLAY=:99`. This is what worked for me.

Comment: Ran into this with Jenkins Xvfb plugin: its default config sets `DISPLAY=:0`, which is invalid. You need to override in job config > build environment > xvfb advanced: "Xvfb display name offset". Easy to track down with `echo $DISPLAY` in your build script.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution here is just run Python with `xvfb-run`:

```sh
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run python <your_file_or_args>
```

Comment: Could you give a quick explanation as to what running python via xvfb-run does? The manpage isn't very helpful

Comment: @YPCrumble xvfb has nothing to do with the executable running inside. The problem is about the selenium version or the firefox used with it. Best way to solve this kind of problems is to attach a copy of firefox with your script instead of run your script inside a environment that you don't control/know.

Comment: @YPCrumble per your question, xvfb-run is same than pipe anything to xvfb, but in a reverse way.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback your Firefox to the previous working version. I suggest 2 versions back. Disable Firefox Maintenance Service.

I was working on a solution and the Firefox Maintenance Service updated Firefox to the latest build in the background. This broke my code and it was giving me this error.

Now it is fixed!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to your Xvfb is not running. So restart your xvfb:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac
```

then check.
This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading firefox from 47 version to 45 or something I'll suggest to upgrade to `47.0.1` or above since they seem to fix an issue.

But if your OS doesn't have new packages in repo (for example Ubuntu 14.04 in time of this answer), you can use debs from ubuntuzilla project:

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_47.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

`sudo dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build_47.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

For x86 use `_i386.deb` postfix.
That sold problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running a recursive chown against not only the python script using selenium, but against the entire virtualenv that script was running in. I changed the ownership to the user running the file. After that, this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, what I did was:

1. Upgrade selenium package

   ```
   sudo pip install -U selenium
   ```
2. Instead of rolling back to older version(like suggested) I rolled up to newer version(48.0, I was previously using V47.0).
   (for upgrading follow the instructions given by Toby Speight but instead of choosing older version choose newer version)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on Windows 10 Build 18363.  I had to call out specifically the Firefoxbinary and the geckdriver executable path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['marionette'] = True

# Path to Firefox binary
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')

# Browser (driver) binary assigned, capabilities, and executable path for the geckodriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=caps,
                           executable_path=r'C:\Users\<name>\python\python-projects\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
# get google.co.in
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score -2):

update your selenuim version ---> pip install -U selenium

Answer (score -7):

It can be solved by changing the file permission of the output file ( or related files to the program).
I used Firefox's webdriver.

Try:

```
chmod -R 777 output_file
```

This solved me the same trouble you have.

Comment: @ZodEnlX

Oh Thank you for your comment!! It is the old post and actually I've given up for this. I should definitely try your solution!! which file's permission should I change? I mean, in your case, which file's permission did you change?