# Python get web page contents that have javascripts - maybe Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I need to analyse web page contents. Page has javascrips. 
Can you advice on better way than using Selenium?

If not:
page when loaded in browser has elements:

```
<div class="js-container">    <table class="zebra" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A1</td>
                <td>A2</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://X" style="color: black">T1</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                ....
            </tr>
....
```

I need to read a table, element by element. I run for example:

`myList = myDriver.find_elements_by_class_name("js-container")`.

Then how do I get inner elements of "js-container" object?

The only element resulting myList has is: `print (myList[0])`:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="61238", element="{71293}")>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need BeautifulSoup - feeding to it Selenium driver.page_source. It is a python tool and it can build a tree based on the web page.
[BeautifulSoup document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Is it the fact that, you want to fetch a page, which will be changed on loading, and you need the result page?

Comment: When I try to use Selenium, I find the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/30103931/5359105 .Try `browser.page_source` to get page to convey it to BS.

Comment: @Ben Lee, looks like browser.page_source does it. Thank you. I wander why it's not documented as one of main features of selenium.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can do this just fine.

```
tableDescendants = myDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.zebra *")
for tableDescendant in tableDescendants
    outer = tableDescendant.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    inner = tableDescendant.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print outer[:outer.find(inner)]
```

This code grabs all descendants of the `TABLE` tag, removes everything after the start of the `innerHTML` string and prints the result. `outerHTML` contains the element itself and all descendants and `innerHTML` contains only the descendants. So, to get only the HTML of the element itself, we need to remove `innerHTML` from `outerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you. How to specify table name with spaces?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a new question. If not, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I mean if not class="zebra", but e.g. class="zebra ver2"

Comment: CSS Selectors is the way to go there. The basic format is `<tagname>.<classname1>.<classname2>`, e.g. `table.zebra.ver2`. Check out these resources: [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) and [CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors).