# Selenium 3.0 + MarionetteDriver + Firefox 48 not working

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

In a simple python test that uses the pytest-selenium plugin, I'm getting the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service wires unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

The test is this:

```
def test_javascript_loads(selenium):
    # Note selenium is a pytest fixture from pytest-selenium
    selenium.get(BASE_URL)
    wait = WebDriverWait(selenium, MAX_LOAD_TIME)
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.title_contains('Project'))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        assert False
```

And it's invoked like this:

```
py.test tests/tests.py -s --driver Firefox --capability marionette 1 --capability binary /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

Also, I've downloaded the latest release of geckodriver, put it in my path, and renamed it to `wires`.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems there's a few hits for that error, all related to the Firefox version in marionette being the cause. Can you test without marionette and a diff browser? eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070834/how-to-fix-selenium-webdriverexception-the-browser-appears-to-have-exited-befor

Comment: Chrome works with the command `py.test tests/tests.py -s --driver Chrome` (after installing chromedriver)