# Firefox 49.0 + Selenium 2.9.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm trying to do testing with Selenium 2 and phpunit. I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar and launch the test firefox opens blank and does nothing.

phpunit gives this message:

```
 PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output
```

Can anyone tell me what happens? Thmks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

You need geckodriver for running tests in latest Firefox browsers. Firefox doesn't support Firefox driver anymore.

1. Download geckodriver and place it in **PATH**
2. Use [Selenium 3.0](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) for running tests

Or use **Firefox 47.*** or **45 ESR** with the old driver.

### Background

[Firefox release 48.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/48.0/releasenotes/) states the following:

> Add-ons that have not been verified and signed by Mozilla will not load

Firefox driver fell under this category, and it had no chances of passing verification without being re-written. Geckodriver, though, is built in the same way as Chromedriver and IEdriver are, and kinda works.

Some more info is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760053/4725998)