# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: setting up X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb)

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a Selenium script running on an Elastic Beanstalk server, to achieve this I am using *pyvirtualdisplay* package following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070834/how-to-fix-selenium-webdriverexception-the-browser-appears-to-have-exited-befor/37760053). However, for the Display driver to run *xvfb* also needs to be installed on the system. I'm getting this error message:

```
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb'
```

Is there any way to manually install this on EB? I have also set up an EC2 server as suggested [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=323740), but the whole process seems unnecessary for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file in *.ebextensions/* like: *.ebextensions/xvfb.config* with the following content:

```
packages:
  yum:
    xorg-x11-server-Xvfb: []
```