# Running Selenium file in Amazon AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

I am running Selenium file on Amazon AWS Ubuntu Server, but I am getting the following error on the below line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome();
```

The error says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I have tried many solutions but it is still not working ([How to fix Selenium WebDriverException: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070834/how-to-fix-selenium-webdriverexception-the-browser-appears-to-have-exited-befor/37760053))

I have also tried with:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
```

and in Firefox, I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Do you install `chromedriver` or `geckodriver` on the server? Your `chromedriver` should be in all of following directory:

```
chromedriver: /usr/bin/chromedriver /bin/chromedriver 
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver /usr/local/chromedriver
```

Or, you can paste path directly:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(path='./chromedriver')`.

Also, use `PyVirtualDisplay`.

Comment: Yes i have already installed gecko or chromedriver . and have also exported in path

Comment: Probably you forgot open virtual display. Here is answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103931/4900574

Comment: I have already posted that link in the question itself . i have tried that solution before asking over here

Comment: Did you try to call driver directly? I mean to paste the absolute path to driver into `path` variable?

Comment: Has chromedriver `+x` permission?

Comment: Have you read this issues https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/26#issuecomment-291914969

Comment: still the same issue , can you help me out ? the script is working fine in my system but in AWS it is not working

Comment: did you install Chrome browser? Chromedriver should support this browser

Answer (score 1):

Since its Amazon AWS please check if Chrome is installed, if not please install from [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome#answer-510063).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to no display in AWS. When you are trying to execute the command `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` or `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` the system tries to launch a Firefox or Chrome browser but because you do not have access to the display in remote access so it is crashing there.

Follow the steps given at [this](https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2) blog and you can create a virtual display to buffer frames. Then your script will not crash due to this problem