# How to fix WebDriverException: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

In my Linux system I use Firefox, execute my program, the error which I've is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "shenma_diff_main_v2.py", line 90, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

If I use root execute my program is OK.

Comment: look at my answer here
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070834/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-the-browser-appears-to/27937810#27937810>

Answer (score 10):

This is because you did not set up correctly to run Firefox without GUI.
This is a tutorial that might be helpful 
[Selenium Headless Automated Testing in Ubuntu](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/)

I think the reason is you need to specify the port number, probably xvfb runs on a different port than Firefox
on one terminal:
`xvfb :99 -ac`
on the another terminal:
`export DISPLAY=:99`
and run your scrapy program
I am successful without using root

Comment: Your comment was not mentioned in the linked answer, but this worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for this, the reference is pretty clear...

Comment: also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039530/unable-to-call-firefox-from-selenium-in-python-on-aws-machine