# Suppress window opening from python script

Tags: python

I have a python script that opens firefox. Is there a way I can run it in the background and suppress the window from popping up? Something like `&` for running in background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060417/python-firefox-headless ?

Comment: @MarcB My bad voted to close as dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `webbrowser` module, you could try passing `autoraise=False` to the `webbrowser.open()` function.