# Not able to run selenium in headless mode on linux server

Tags: python, django, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Error:**

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

**Description:**

I'm following this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-setup-selenium-on-a-linux-vm-cd19ee47d922) and [official document](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) to install and setup **Selenium** in headless mode on my server. When I run it locally on my server, it works, but when I access it after setting up **Nginx** and a **Service** file for my **Django** site, it gives me the above error. After looking at several answers, I checked these points, and they exist in my project or in my system.

- google chrome browser (version - 111)
- selenium installed
- chrome driver (version - 111)
- added chrome driver in `$PATH`

above points I've added if I'm missing somthing or any other information required please let me know.

Comment: Did you try adding  `--disable-sandbox`  ? You can't run chrome without this flag as root.

Comment: Also, what do you get when running `/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless=new --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage` ?

Comment: Hii @kaliiiiiiiii Yes, I forgot to add that point I've tried with `--disable-sandbox`, `--disable-dev-shm-usage`

Comment: Ever manage to fix this?

Comment: No, It was side project so I didn't tried after this question but I think using [Xorg](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg) while deploying it will work according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207749/14457833) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfWZmoYC6i4).