# Selenium ChromeDriver / Flask Gunicorn, working in normal mode but failing in daemon mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, selenium-chromedriver, gunicorn

I have a simple Flask app and the ChromeDriver is instantiated as such

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
....
```

This code is working fine when I invoke it via following commands

```
python app.py
gunicorn wsgi:app -b :5000
```

However, when I use run it as a daemon mode, I get following error

```
gunicorn[31543]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
gunicorn[31543]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
gunicorn[31543]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
gunicorn[31543]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
gunicorn[31549]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
gunicorn[31549]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
gunicorn[31549]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
gunicorn[31549]: /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
```

The contents of my service file is

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myproject
Environment="PATH=/var/www/myproject/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn --timeout 1000 -b :5000 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

google-chrome is properly installed. when I invoke this command

```
which google-chrome
```

I get following output

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

I think I am missing something when it comes to running the Flask app in daemon mode that is causing the issue.

I check the permission for google-chrome and its listed as such.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          31 Feb 19 00:55  google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          32 Feb 19 00:55  google-chrome-stable -> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Comment: You've to specify your chrome bin file path inside your `Environment` variable of service file  eg. `Environment="PATH=/var/www/myproject/bin:/usr/bin/google-chrome"`

Comment: After you solved chrome issue you may face this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75876210/14457833). There are some solutions in comment section you can check that. Your code will work in you local system but if you deploy it on non GUI server it will raise error which I've referenced in my question.