# Disable hardware inputs on Selenium webdriver firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a ruby script to test a web page in Firefox. it sends mouse or keyboard events pragmatically to Browser but when hardware mouse is moved, it affects my test.

How can i configure Firefox to forget hardware mouse and keyboard events?

Comment: I would avoid relying upon mouse or keyboard events if possible. Is there any way to use the DOM?

Comment: The movement of mouse on page causes some objects hide on screen. actually I don't want my objects disappear.

Comment: So you want to test the on mouse over events of the page?

Comment: are you saying that selenium webdriver actually moves your mouse cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Xvfb` which will provide a virtual screen for Firefox to open in. Basically you start `Xvfb` with a screen number in and point Firefox at that screen by running `export DISPLAY=:XX`. You could use PhantomJS but I wouldn't recommend it because it's doubtful that any users will ever use it; better to test with a browser that people use.

Info on setting up `Xvfb`

http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

[How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the headless browser [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It works with webdriver and pretty much all Ruby testing tools. Being headless, you must send mouse and keyboard events programmatically. The user's mouse and keyboard will have no effect.

You will also notice that the tests are faster!