# Scrapy PhantomJs slow linux

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape contents from [this](http://www.vivino.com/wine-regions/sardinia) page on my linux machine. I want to display all the list of wines by clicking the `show more` button [around 600] until no show more buttons appear. I'm using `selenium` and `PhantomJS` for handling javascripts. I'm using `time.sleep()` show that once i click the `show more` button, it sleeps for some short time until another appears. The problem i'm facing is, initially the program clicks the show more button quickly but once it reaches around 100-150 clicks, the time taken to detect the `show more` button increases at an alarming rate, taking too much time. Below is the code that detects the `show more` button and clicks it.

```
    def parse(self,response):

     sel = Selector(self.driver.get(response.url))

     self.driver.get(response.url)
     click = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn-more-wines']")

     try:
        while click:
            click[0].click()
            time.sleep(2)
     except Exception:
        print 'no clicks'
```

Comment: Yes, the page gets bigger and there is more content to parse through.

Answer (score 1):

An [*Explicit Wait*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) (instead of `time.sleep()`) can make a positive impact here:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='btn-more-wines']")))
```

This would basically wait for the "Show More" button to become clickable.

---

Another possible improvement could be achieved by switching to Chrome in a headless mode (with a virtual display):

- [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)