# Setting a test using xvfb + PyCharm + vagrant

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, xvfb

I have this environment:

- PyCharm running on Mac OS X
- Python3.4 environment running on Ubuntu Server in a vagrant instance

I want to be able to run/debug tests using PyCharm. So far I can do it but I recently added selenium to my tests now I need to wrap the python interpreter within *xvfb-run* remote command. I tried adding a remote external tool but I can't make it work yet. I found [this guy](http://pyselenium.tumblr.com/) but he doesn't explain very well how he made it. Any idea would be very appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/394647), I solved without adding an external tool. Steps:

- Installed xvfbwrapper on remote python environment
- Code sample:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
  from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

  class UITestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
      fixtures = ['data.json']

      @classmethod
      def setUpClass(cls):
          cls.vdisplay = Xvfb()
          cls.vdisplay.start()
          cls.selenium = WebDriver()
          cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(3000)
          super(UITestCase, cls).setUpClass()

      @classmethod
      def tearDownClass(cls):
          cls.selenium.quit()
          cls.vdisplay.stop()
          super(UITestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

      def test_list(self):
          self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/#/app'))

          count = len(self.selenium.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="data"]/tbody/tr'))
          self.assertEqual(count, 2)
  ```
- No changes needed to your test configuration (assuming it already ran successfully)