# Python + Selenium + PhantomJS => Problems loading and rendering pages with local development server

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm saving an screenshot when the page is loaded. If I test it with production, it works OK (the page is rendered correctly). **But**, if I test with local development server, the page isn't rendered correctly when I check the screenshot. *Some elements (HTML, images) are missing.*

The problems is PhantomJS. If I use Firefox, it works OK. But I need 'headless', because it's a requirement.

I'm using Python 2.7.6 + Selenium 2.45.0 + PhantomJS 1.9.8 (OS X Yosemite 10.10).

*Code*:

```
import unittest
import time

from selenium import webdriver

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    HEADLESS = 1
    DEVELOPMENT = 1

    def setUp(self):

        if self.HEADLESS:
             self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
             self.driver.set_window_size(1400, 1200)
         else:
             self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
             self.driver.maximize_window()

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(100)

        url = 'http'
        if self.DEVELOPMENT:
            url += '://development.localhost.lan:3000/login'
        else:
            url += 's://PRODUCTION_WEB.com/login'

        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.save_screenshot('login.png')

    def tearDown(self):
        print 'tearDown'

    def test_import(self):
        print 'test_import'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Also, I've tested the following, with **no** results:

- service_args=['--local-to-remote-url-access=true']
- service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'] : (production is http**s**)
- set user_agent
- enable/disable cookies
- activate localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled

Please, could anyone give me any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just FYI, if `phantomjs` is the reason for your headaches and it makes you violent, you can approach it with firefox or chrome with a **virtual display**, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe! 
Finally, I couldn't find a workaround with PhantomJS, so I'm using **xvfb**.

[Reference](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless)

> xvfb-run python tests.py