# Using selenium at hosted app?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click one button with my Django app that I have hosted at DigitalOcean.

Here it is how I do it offline:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get("http://www.hltv.org/match/2296366-gplay-gamers2-acer-predator-masters-powered-by-intel")

element = firefox.find_element_by_id("voteteam1")
element.click()
```

But can I use it online? Maybe there is other solution?

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say 'you want to do it online' ?

Comment: At my hosted Django app. I am confused because using offline it opens firefox. But how this situation will be handled online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tied up to Firefox or any other browser "with a head", the common approach is to start a *"Virtual Display"* with the help of [`PyVirtualDisplay`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) which is a wrapper around `Xvfb`, `Xephyr` and `Xvnc`, see this answer for an [example working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/771848).

---

Another option would be to use a *"headless" browser*, such as [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/). In this case, the change is usually very simple, replacing:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
```

with:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Assuming you have `PhantomJS` installed.

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("http://www.hltv.org/match/2296366-gplay-gamers2-acer-predator-masters-powered-by-intel")
>>> driver.title
u'HLTV.org - Hot Match: GPlay vs Gamers2'
```

---

The third option (mine most favorite) would be use a remote selenium server, either your own, or provided by third-party services like [`BrowserStack`](http://browserstack.com/) or [`Sauce Labs`](http://saucelabs.com/). [Example code](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/python):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

desired_cap = {'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': 'xp', 'browser': 'IE', 'browser_version': '7.0' }

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://username:key@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=desired_cap)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
if not "Google" in driver.title:
    raise Exception("Unable to load google page!")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("BrowerStack")
elem.submit()
print driver.title
driver.quit()
```

In case of `BrowserStack` or `Sauce Labs` you have an enormous amount of browsers and operating systems to choose from. Note that these are not free services and you would need a `username` and a `key` for this code to work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use firefox as headless on a Linux box. The following articles should help -

http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/