# How to extract CSS styles using Scrapy

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

i am web scraping using scrapy and selenium webdrivers. But i find selenium webdriver to be very slow, but i find it easier to extract CSS properties of a webelement eg.

```
webElement.value_of_css_property('font-size')
```

how can this be achieved using scrapy only and no selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you **have to have a rendered content in a real browser**. `Scrapy` downloader is not a browser and has only the initial HTML page, there is no javascript engine built-in and it cannot download additional CSS or JS files.

With `Scrapy` you can only get the `style` attribute value of an element, but nothing more than that. `selenium` is the tool for the job.

Note that you can avoid having a real display as a dependency and automate [`phantomjs`](http://phantomjs.org/) headless browser or other browsers in a [virtual display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb).