# How to hold the cache in selenium in a loop after a page gets refreshed?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using this spider to click on the color and then page gets refreshed and then subsequent clicking on the links but it breaks in between and throw **Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Error** How to get hold of original page after completion of loop?

Couldn't find any suitable solution for this.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time

class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    model_name = scrapy.Field()
    model_link = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    what = scrapy.Field()
    seller = scrapy.Field()

class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "extract"
    allowed_domains = ["mysmartprice.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/huawei-honor-holly-msp4857"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(criticspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.download_delay = 0.25
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.maximize_window()

        self.browser.implicitly_wait(20)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)

        # waiting for "Go to store" to become visible
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.store_pricetable")))

        main_window = self.browser.window_handles[0]

        # iterate over featured stores and visit them
        for i,store in enumerate(self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.store_pricetable")):
            link = store.find_element_by_css_selector("div.store_gostore > div.storebutton")
            ActionChains(self.browser).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).move_to_element(link).click(link).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()

            # there is a popup preventing us to navigate to the store URL - close it 
            try:
                popup_close = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".popup-closebutton")
                popup_close.click()

                # repeat the click
                ActionChains(self.browser).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).move_to_element(link).click(link).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass

            button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]').click()

            #time.sleep(5)
            item = CompItem()
            sel = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source)
            item["what"] = "url"
            item["seller"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="store_rating_bar_out"]/@data-storename').extract()[i]
            item["model_name"] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@itemprop,"brand")]/text()').extract()[0] +" "+sel.xpath('//span[contains(@itemprop,"name")]/text()').extract()[0] + sel.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"variant")]/text()').extract()[0]
            # shift+click on the "Go to Store" link


            # switch to the newly opened window, read the current url and close the window
            self.browser.switch_to.window(self.browser.window_handles[-1])

            # wait until "On your way to the store" would not be in title
            wait.until(lambda browser: "On your way to the Store" not in browser.title)

            item['url'] = self.browser.current_url
            yield item
            self.browser.close()

            # switch back to the main window
            self.browser.switch_to.window(main_window)
            self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "r")
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
```

Comment: You can't. You'll need to loop through the page again keeping track of what you've already done.