# Shorthand for OR'ing XPaths (same query but multiple tag types)?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xhtml

A job listing containing a given string may be headed by a `<h2>`, `<h3>`, or `<p>` (typically). I can use `|` to logical OR these so that my XPath will detect all cases:

```
//h2[contains(., 'Project Manager')] | //h3[contains(., 'Project Manager')] | //p[contains(., 'Project Manager')]
```

Is there shorthand available to us here?

Comment: Careful: the "|" operator is not a logical OR, it is a set union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` and `name()` to check the element's name:

```
//*[name() = 'h2' or name() = 'h3' or name() = 'p'][contains(., 'Project Manager')]
```

Or, as @kjhughes pointed out, the `self::` would make it even shorter and more readable:

```
//*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::p][contains(., 'Project Manager')]
```

Comment: Nicely done. Thanks. And thanks also for http://stackoverflow.com/a/35143170/1389110 which I will look into further.

Comment: @Pyderman Please take care of your previous questions. Many of them have answers that you have not accepted. Asking many questions is not the wrong thing to do, but please take the time to finish the old ones first. And by "finish" I mean accepting an answer, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
//(h2|h3|p)[contains(., 'Project Manager')]
```

(Apart from requiring XPath 2.0, perhaps)

Comment: Nice approach Michael, thanks. Yes lxml, the Python library which is performing the XPath, would appear to be using XPath 1.0 I'm afraid.