# Executing a page's JavaScript at a low level with Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml, urllib2

When [this](https://www.geckoboard.com/careers/) page is scraped with urllib2:

```
url = https://www.geckoboard.com/careers/
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
```

the following element (the link to the job) is nowhere to be found in the source (`content`)

[image]

Taking a look at the full source that gets rendered in a browser:

[image]

So it would appear that the FRONT-END ENGINEER element is dynamically loaded by Javascript. Is it possible to have this Javascript executed by urllib2 (or other low-level library) without involving e.g. Selenium, BeautifulSoup, or other?

Comment: No, unless you can hunt around enough in the page JS to figure out where that link is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The pieces of information are loaded using some `ajax request`. You could use `firebug` extension for `mozilla` or google chrome has it's own tool to get theese details. Just hit `f12` in google chrome while opening the URL. You can find the complete details there.

There you will find a request with url `https://app.recruiterbox.com/widget/13587/openings/`

Information from the above url is rendered in that web page.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are building something *generic* for multiple web-sites and don't want to go deep down in how a certain site is loaded, what requests are made under-the-hood to construct the page. In this case, a *real browser is your friend* - load the page in a real browser automated via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) - then, once the page is loaded, pass the `.page_source` to `lxml.html` (from what I see this is your HTML parser of choice) for further parsing.

If you don't want a browser to show up or you don't have a display, you can go headless - [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) or a regular browser on a [virtual display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb).

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
driver.get("https://www.geckoboard.com/careers/")

# TODO: you might need a delay here

tree = fromstring(driver.page_source)

driver.close()

# TODO: parse HTML
```

You should also know that, there are plenty of [methods to locate elements in selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) and you might not even need a separate HTML parser here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash