# In order to run my tests headless, i used HTMLUnit but my tests fail and not able to find ID's

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Installed `Xvfb` using `pip install robotframework-xvfb`. Even after successful installation, on running tests i get below error

> XVFB sample
>   | FAIL | EnvironmentError: Can not find Xvfb. Please install it and
>   try again.

Comment: Does it have to be xvfb? You could also try with phantomjs headless browser (based on webkit).

Comment: Is the program `Xvfb` installed, and the location on your PATH? If you go to a command line prompt and run the command `Xvfb`, what happens?

Comment: It says Xvfb is not a rcognised command. Do i have to specify the path in env variables too??

Comment: yes, as I stated in my answer below.  If you're doing as Bryan said, your system doesn't have a reference to where xvfb is located and therefore cannot start/stop or interact with it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to this question and its answers - [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)

In short, are you starting xvfb before running your tests?  If you're all clear here, it sounds like perhaps you have a PATH environment variable issue