# Getting GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays error in debian

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, debian, headless-browser

Actually i am trying to run a headless browser in remote debian server through selenium. I have firefox 46.0.1 installed in the server and i am using selenium 2.53.1 version.

Whenever i tried to run a given test i got the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

I have instantiated firefox driver in my code like this:

```
saDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Java. However in Python this issue can be solved by the following method, this may help you

**If it says Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays then install pyvirtualdisplay:**

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay selenium
```

You might need xvfb too:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then try adding this code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Full example:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')

browser.close()
display.stop()
```

Comment: Getting this error when running the above sample code: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH`

Comment: selenium cannot find your gecko driver executable. Make sure it is under usr/bin folder... if you are running ubuntu  and executable.

Comment: It's actually working for me, Thanks. Python 3.6 + PyVirtualDisplay (0.2.1) + selenium (3.12.0) + geckodriver 0.19.1 + Mozilla Firefox 52.7.3
 + CentOS + Putty

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the display in the shell that selenium server is running in otherwise it will not be able to open the browser.

```
nohup sudo Xvfb: 10 - ac &
export DISPLAY=10
```