# cannot start selenium.WebDriver firefox in java in a box with no UI

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, xvfb

I have a something like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

class Gecko { 


...
FirefoxBinary ffB = new FirefoxBinary();
ffB.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":10");
...
options.setBinary(ffB);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Then I start a virtual frame buffer with:

```
Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

But when I run with Selenium:

```
java -cp .:selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar Gecko
```

the following problem shows:

> 1508364524466  geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
>   Error: **GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays**
>   Exception in thread "main" **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused**

Which could be a possible cause? User permission? Firewall? The current box doesn't have any desktop environment installed.

Comment: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789338/getting-gdk-backend-does-not-match-available-displays-error-in-debian) Perhaps you can take help from this link.

Answer (score 0):

If it says Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays then install pyvirtualdisplay:

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay selenium
You might need xvfb too:

sudo apt-get install xvfb
Then try adding this code:

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
Full example:

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')

browser.close()
display.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks, 
but that doesn't solve my problem.
It helps me in the sense that I can use selenium with python + pyvirtualdisplay
but I'm trying to use it with java + xvfb.

I've said that I do:
    Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
in java... 
    ffB.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":10");

but when I run Gecko it shows in output:
1508525094630 geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

when running line:
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);