# What is difference between Xvfb and Chromedriver and when to use them

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

Hi I am planning to setup selenium to test my web application.

I have read that both chromedriver and Xvfb can be used to run the tests.
I have also read that Xvfb can be configured to use chromdriver.

So that got me confused. What role does chromedriver and Xvfb in runnning the selenium tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. chromedriver - to run tests on **chrome** browser (with GUI).
2. Xvfb  - to run tests in **headless** mode. can be any browser including chrome (Browser GUI won't be displayed, so you can use the machine for some other operations).

**code snippets (python):**

Chrome Driver (download [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome() // to launch tests in Chrome browser.
```

Xvfb - using pyvirtualdisplay (python wrapper for Xvfb) :

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Chrome will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

References:

1. [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)

Comment: This doesn't work on a desktop. It just launches a conventional browser, even though `visible=0` is specified. How do you test with this on a system with an active X server? How does Selenium know to use the Xvfb wrapper instead of the default DISPLAY connection?

Comment: Hi Cerin, were you able to figure out how to launch Xvfb on your local desktop... I'm meeting a similar issue to yours...