# How to run headless browser where web page(browser) requires keyboard intervention

Tags: headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, xvfb

I am trying to run automation script written using python, selenium and pyrobot on google chrome. The browser requires keyboard intervention and there is no way I can avoid it. I have used pyrobot class for listening keystrokes. I want to run browser in headless mode in background. But the keystrokes is not working in background, rather its effect is seen on active window. I tried **xvfb** but the problem remained the same. 
Reference: [What is difference between Xvfb and Chromedriver and when to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460168/what-is-difference-between-xvfb-and-chromedriver-and-when-to-use-them)