# How to hide Firefox window (Selenium WebDriver) in python test

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python test and I want to run it without opening the firefox

I want to hide it so how can I do this ?

any help ?

Comment: "Python test" is a bit unclear. You mean you want to run a site UI test using selenium? In that case, you can use PhantomJS (with selenium as well), it is a browser running in background without any kind of graphical interface and, obviously, windows.

Answer (score 23):

[Headless:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0cec0cd3a468b3de2ad62f7db23dcdef01ec1120/selenium__examples/hide_window__invisible__headless.py)

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/doodles')

print('Title: "{}"'.format(driver.title))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set negative window position to hide browser:

```
driver.set_window_position(-3000, 0) # driver.set_window_position(0, 0) to get it back
```

or try [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) headless browser, that allow to run `UI` tests without displaying browser window

Comment: yes I need to runit backgroud so I prefer to use  PhantomJS

Comment: how can I use  PhantomJS ? should I change python code to use it ? should I import sth ?

Comment: Download binary, put it in your `Python` root folder and define your `driver` as `driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()`

Comment: no, nothing to import additionally. But note that `PhantomJS` has a lot of bugs, so it works not so good as `Firefox` or `Chrome`...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/2929488

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```