# Headless Chrome does not start

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, headless

I have following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

driver.get("*some site*")
```

When i start debugging, it stucks at the `driver.get("*some site*")` line. It simply does not start anything.
Any suggestions please?
Everything is up to date. Using windows 7. 
EDIT: using Python 3.6

EDIT 2: [hope its helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S0Xk.png)

Comment: I believe it always needs a display. You should take a look at `virtual displays` since you are in a headless environment. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)

Comment: well, i used to use PhantomJS, but since it had some problems with locating elements, i tried using this.
Anyway thx for suggestion.

Comment: I have looked on those virtual displays and it looks like i cant use them on windows machine, or am i wrong?

Comment: Update the question with the version info of the binaries you are using along with the error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: thanks for you reply, however, how to provide these informations please? I mean, where do I find them. Kinda new to python, thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

try running with this options, for me (on my win machine) --no-sandbox helped.
 --log-path and verbose obviously helps with debugging.

```
ch_options.add_argument('--headless')
ch_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
ch_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
ch_options.add_argument('--log-path=chromedriver.log')
ch_options.add_argument('--verbose')
```

and for user agent (in case some websites protest):

```
ch_options.add_argument(
    '--user-agent="valid user agent :)"')
```

and starting it:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=ch_options)
```

my chromedriver is in PATH environmental variable so no need to pass executable in here.

btw. phantomjs driver is not updated any more so try to resolve this and switch to chromedriver. I.e. for me the phantomjs driver wont even let me change user-agent, just on python binding though.

Comment: Does not work for me. Still looks like it stucks on driver.get("****") line.

Comment: post the outpout of running it with --verbose or just paste the content of logs, it should has some details.

Comment: It does not output any errors/exceptions. Where do I find that log please? It just looks like it freezes on that driver.get. After 10 minutes of work it said something like "request timeout".

Comment: I used the following code you have suggested, nothing changed.

Comment: If you will run it with this option --log-path=chromedriver.log it should log it in directory in which you're running script so if its C:\folder\script.py and you run it from that directory, you can as well use full path.

Comment: and does it work when running in standard (non-headless) mode so starting up chrome and getting to webpage etc.?

Comment: yeah, in normal mode (headed or how to call it) it just runs fine.