# Beautiful Soup can't find the part of the HTML I want

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-beautifultable

I've been using BeautifulSoup for Web Scraping for a while and this is the first time I encountered a problem like this. I am trying to select the number 101,172 in the code but even though I use .find or .select, the output is always only the tag, not the number. I worked with similar data collection before and hadn't had any problems

```
<div class="legend-block legend-block--pageviews">
      <h5>Pageviews</h5><hr>
      <div class="legend-block--body">
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Pageviews:
          <span class="pull-right">
            101,172
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Daily average:
          <span class="pull-right">
            4,818
          </span>
        </div></div></div>
```

I used:

```
res = requests.get(wiki_page, timeout =None)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ab=soup.select('span[class="pull-right"]')
#print(i)
print(ab)
```

output:

```
[<span class="pull-right">\n<label class="logarithmic-scale">\n<input 
class="logarithmic-scale-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Logarithmic scale      
</label>\n</span>, <span class="pull-right">\n<label class="begin-at- 
zero">\n<input class="begin-at-zero-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Begin at 
zero      </label>\n</span>, <span class="pull-right">\n<label class="show- 
labels">\n<input class="show-labels-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Show 
values      </label>\n</span>]
```

Additionally, the data number I am looking for is dynamic, so I am not sure if Javascript would affect BeautifulSoup

Comment: Well, how did you try to get the value? We need at least a snippet to check what could be going wrong in your code.

Comment: strange, if you put the html snippet through BeautifulSoup and then do find_all for span and apply .text on the return you will get your 101,172..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Data Web Scraping with Python, BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984646/dynamic-data-web-scraping-with-python-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''<div class="legend-block legend-block--pageviews">
      <h5>Pageviews</h5><hr>
      <div class="legend-block--body">
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Pageviews:
          <span class="pull-right">101,172
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Daily average:
          <span class="pull-right">
            4,818
          </span>
        </div></div></div>'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "linear-legend--counts"})
span = div.find('span')
text = span.get_text()
print(text)
```

**output:**

```
101,172
```

simply in one line:

```
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find("div", {"class": "linear-legend--counts"}).find('span').get_text()
```

**EDIT:**

As OP has posted another question which can be a possible duplicate for this one, He had found an answer. For someone who is looking for an answer for a similar kind of a question I will post the accepted answer for this question. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985365/5430055).

The javascript code won't get executed if you retrieve page with the requests.get. So the selenium shall be used instead. It will mimic user like behaviour with the opening of the page in browser, so the js code will be executed.

To start with selenium, you need to install with `pip install selenium`. Then to retrieve your item use code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
# List of the page url and selector of element to retrieve.
wiki_pages = [("https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi",
               ".summary-column--container .legend-block--pageviews .linear-legend--counts:first-child span.pull-right"),]
for wiki_page in wiki_pages:
    url = wiki_page[0]
    selector = wiki_page[1]
    browser.get(wiki_page)
    page_views_count = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    print page_views_count.text
browser.quit()
```

**NOTE**: If you need to run headless browser, consider using [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/) (a wrapper for [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)) to run headless WebDriver tests, see '[How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)' for more information.

Comment: I have to do this process for many pages so I choose the entire html tag with soup.select('html') and equal it to variable html and the process is the same as yours. However, in the variable html, I still can not get the value. Might it be because it is a dynamic data that changes according to page?

Comment: give me an example url

Comment: https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi                 Pageviews is what I want