# Dynamic Data Web Scraping with Python, BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract this data(number) for many pages from the HTML. The data is different for each page. When I try to use soup.select('span[class="pull-right"]') it should give me the number, but only the tag comes. I believe it is because Javascript is used in the webpage. 180,476 is the position of data at this specific HTML that I want for many pages:

```
<div class="legend-block--body">
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Pageviews:
          <span class="pull-right">
            180,476
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="linear-legend--counts">
          Daily average:
          <span class="pull-right">
            8,594
          </span>
        </div></div>
```

My code(this is in a loop to work for many pages):

```
res = requests.get(wiki_page, timeout =None)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ab=soup.select('span[class="pull-right"]')
print(ab)
```

output:

```
[<span class="pull-right">\n<label class="logarithmic-scale">\n<input 
class="logarithmic-scale-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Logarithmic scale      
</label>\n</span>, <span class="pull-right">\n<label class="begin-at- 
zero">\n<input class="begin-at-zero-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Begin at 
zero      </label>\n</span>, <span class="pull-right">\n<label class="show- 
labels">\n<input class="show-labels-option" type="checkbox"/>\n        Show 
values      </label>\n</span>]
```

Example URL:https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi

I want the Pageviews

Comment: You probably need `selenium` to extract that value

Comment: wow....whats the difference ? .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982930/beautiful-soup-cant-find-the-part-of-the-html-i-want#comment90915580_51982930

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript code won't get executed if you retrieve page with the requests.get. So the selenium shall be used instead. It will mimic user like behaviour with the opening of the page in browser, so the js code will be executed.

To start with selenium, you need to install with `pip install selenium`. Then to retrieve your item use code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
# List of the page url and selector of element to retrieve.
wiki_pages = [("https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi",
               ".summary-column--container .legend-block--pageviews .linear-legend--counts:first-child span.pull-right"),]
for wiki_page in wiki_pages:
    url = wiki_page[0]
    selector = wiki_page[1]
    browser.get(wiki_page)
    page_views_count = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    print page_views_count.text
browser.quit()
```

**NOTE**: If you need to run headless browser, consider using [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/) (a wrapper for [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)) to run headless WebDriver tests, see '[How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)' for more information.

Comment: I believe the selector is not correct because it says it can't find the location

Comment: I got the idea. I am on the right track for sure. But the above .find_element_by_css_selector(selector) and my other different trials for search always give: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="195cd940ff11cbbe3ac113970aaa3025", element="0.49495071437839355-1")> EDIT: I got it, you gotta make the page load up first so just add these two lines: browser.maximize_window() 
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the python plugin selenium. 
It requires you to download a driver for whatever browser you are using.
You will then be able to use selenium to pull out values from the html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("pull-right")
// or the following below 
//element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
//element = driver.find_element_by_id("html ID name")
//element = driver.find_element_by_name("html element name")
//element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwd-id']")
print(element)
driver.close()
```