# How can I force my program to use an updated version of chrome when using it in headless mode?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have a python script which uses Google Chrome to perform some tasks in [Youtube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com). The script works as expected when I disable `options.add_argument('--headless')`, but when I use it with the headless option it's unable to find some elements, so I decided to take an screenshot to see what was going on.

[image]

It looks like, for some reason, when I use the headless mode, the executed Chrome version is older.

I have also tried to change the user agent: `options.add_argument("--user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36")`, but it doesn't work.

How can I execute an updated version of Chrome using headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this involves using https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay in order to simulate a headed display in a headless environment such as Linux. (This can help you get around issues that might only appear when loading a website with a headless browser.) The virtual display uses `Xvfb`, and there's actually a very popular Stack Overflow solution here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672

Here's a summary of the previous solution for your situation:

To install:

```bash
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

And here's how to use it in your Python code:

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
# display is active / Run your selenium code
# ----------
display.stop()
# display is stopped
```

After putting it all together with your code, it may look something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
# ...
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)
# ...
display.stop()
```

(Make modifications as necessary, such as the screen resolution, etc.)

There are some Selenium Python frameworks that already have the virtual display built-in (such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), which activates the virtual display via an added `pytest` command-line arg: `--xvfb`.) Each framework that has the feature built-in may do things a bit differently.

Just be sure NOT to run Chrome in headless mode if you use this solution. The virtual display should allow you to run a regular headed Chrome in a headless environment using Xvfb.